# Initializing a Java object in a separate method: why this won't work

Tags: java, methods, constructor, initialization

Here's a thing that I can't tell I'm surprised it won't work, but anyway it's interesting for me to find the explanation of this case.
Imagine we have an object:

```
SomeClass someClass = null;
```

And a method that will take this object as a parameter to initialize it:

```
public void initialize(SomeClass someClass) {
  someClass = new SomeClass();
}
```

And then when we call:

```
initialize(someClass);
System.out.println("" + someClass);
```

It will print:

```
null
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java pass by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I pass parameters by reference in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068760/can-i-pass-parameters-by-reference-in-java)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's impossible to do in java. In C# you'd pass the parameter using the `ref` or `out` keyword. There are no such keywords in java. You can see this question for details: [Can I pass parameters by reference in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068760/can-i-pass-parameters-by-reference-in-java)

Incidentally, for that same reason you cannot write a swap function in java that would swap two integers.

Answer (score 1):

As Armen mentioned, what you want to do is not possible this way. Why not use a [factory method?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

> And a method that will take this object as a parameter to initialize it:

The method does not take an **object** as a parameter in your case. It takes a reference which points to null. Then it copies this reference and points it to a new instance of `SomeClass`. But obviously, the reference that you passed as a parameter still points to **null**.