# Equivalent of AtomicReference but without the volatile synchronization cost

Tags: java, reference

What is the equivalent of:

```
AtomicReference<SomeClass> ref = new AtomicReference<SomeClass>( ... );
```

but without the synchronization cost.  Note that I *do* want to wrap a reference inside another object.

I've looked at the classes extending the *Reference* abstract class but I'm a bit lost amongst all the choices.

I need something really simple, not weak nor phantom nor all the other references besides one.  Which class should I use?

Comment: Wait, AtomicReference is synchronized? Where do you infer this? It would contradict the whole idea behind it.

Comment: @Viruzzo: reworded the question... I want to avoid the synchronization cost due to the use of the *volatile* keyword.

Comment: Everyone needs to understand that synchronization != `synchronized`, it may be in fact `synchronized` but synchronization just implies some form of mutual exclusion/memory guarantees.  Relative to non-synchronized/thread-safe obejcts, an AtomicReference is expensive.

Comment: It still is misleading: there is no "synchronization" cost with volatile, just a performance impact due to not having cached copies of the value in each thread. Synchronization happens when thread have to check, stop and resume execution because they can't concurrently access the value.

Comment: @John Vint: exactly... +1 to your comment.  I think some people not understanding this did downvote me : (

Comment: You're playing on words now but ok...  But then, as "John Vint" wrote: relative to non-synchronized/thread-safe objects, an AtomicReference is expensive".  I want the same functionality, but from a single thread.  Hence I want something less expensive than an AtomicReference.

Comment: @Viruzzo: what word would you use to describe the *"performance impact due to not having cached copies of the value in each thread"*? Some threads have to then use some "shared memory" and that has an impact.  It's a "concurrency impact"?

Comment: Of course it has a cost/impact, it's just not the same as full synchronization (and operates differently); it's not "playing on words", those are different words with different meanings. Anyway, "I want the same functionality" but which functionality? The reason to use AtomicReference is in concurrency situations, so what do you want to accomplish without it being volatile?

Comment: @JohnVint - You say "synchronization != `synchronized`". Yet the [Wikipedia article on synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29) says: _"Thread synchronization or serialization, strictly defined, is the application of particular mechanisms to ensure that two concurrently-executing threads or processes do not execute specific portions of a program at the same time. If one thread has begun to execute a serialized portion of the program, any other thread trying to execute this portion must wait until the first thread finishes."_ `synchronized`!

Comment: A couple things.  1.  That is thread-synchronization, our discussion about the AtomicReference and synchronization cost deals with data-synchronization (which is located in that link you supplied).  More importantly you can read on the cahce-synchronization.  Volatile writes, depending on the system, can use cache coherence (which is non-blocking but a form of synchronization).

Comment: 2. Synchronization is applied to non-blocking algorithms.  You can read Herlihy's paper on wait-free synchronization http://www.cs.brown.edu/~mph/Herlihy91/p124-herlihy.pdf.  All wait-free algorithms are lock-free so wait-free synchronization implies lock freedom which also implies no `synchronized`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are simply trying to store a reference in an object. Can't you create a class with a field, considering the field would be a strong reference that should achieve what you want

You shouldn't create a StrongReference class (because it would be silly) but to demonstrate it

```
public class StrongReference{
  Object refernece;

  public void set(Object ref){
    this.reference =ref;
  }
  public Object get(){
    return this.reference;
  }

}
```

Comment: +1 but...  Using *AtomicReference* I can use generics to precise which kind of reference I can put in.  Isn't really anything already existing for strong references?  I mean, I *could* write one myself, just like I *could* rewrite all the methods in the *String* class etc. : )

Comment: Java is pretty strict about not having semantically meaningless things like this, especially when you can write it in less than 10 lines of code (like with C++'s Pair).

Comment: I don't see that as meaningless; it's a container for a reference, which is useful for generating side-effects out of lambdas. Otherwise things can get ugly with things like method chaining. I know functional programming style discourages this kind of thing, but sometimes it's useful and it makes for more readable code.

Comment: It's like a pointer to a pointer.  Useful when you want to "point" to something that could be `null` or any value, but where the absence of the pointer itself (by means of it being `null`) means something else.

Answer (score 9):

If you want a reference without thread safety you can use an array of one.

```
MyObject[] ref = { new MyObject() };
MyObject mo = ref[0];
ref[0] = n;
```

Answer (score 4):

To use java.util.**concurrent**.**atomic**.**Atomic**Reference feels wrong to me too in order to share a reference of an object. Besides the "atomicity costs" AtomicReference is full of methods that are irrelevant for your use case and may raise wrong expectations to the user.
But I haven't encounter such an equivalent class in the JDK yet.

Here is a summary of your options - chose what fits best to you:

- A self-written value container like the proposed `StrongReference` or `MyReference` from the other answers
- [MutableObject](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/latest/org/apache/commons/lang3/mutable/MutableObject.html) from Apache Commons Lang
- Array with length == 1 or a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) with size == 1
- [setPlain(V)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#setPlain-V-) and [getPlain()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#getPlain--) in `AtomicReference` since Java 9

Comment: I like Apache Commons Lang MutableObject, it's made for this.

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 9 you can now use `AtomicReference.setPlain()` and `AtomicReference.getPlain()`.

JavaDoc on `setPlain`:
"Sets the value to newValue, with memory semantics of setting as if the variable was declared non-volatile and non-final."

Answer (score 2):

AtomicReference does not have the cost of synchronization in the sense of traditional synchronized sections. It is implemented as non-blocking, meaning that threads that wait to "acquire the lock" are not context-switched, which makes it very fast in practice. Probably for concurrently updating a single reference, you cannot find a faster method.

Comment: +1 but I need the same functionality in a single thread.  Do I really need to write a strong reference wrapper myself or is there already on?   I do no not the concurrent updating, hence my question...

Comment: My advice is to simply try to benchmark the AtomicReference for a large number of calls and see if there is any significant penalty with respect to a normal wrapper like the one suggested by John Vint.

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to use `AtomicReference` but don't want to incur the cost of the volatile write you can use `lazySet`

The write doesn't issue a memory barrier that a normal volatile write does, but the get still invokes a volatile load (which is relatively cheap)

```
AtomicReference<SomeClass> ref = new AtomicReference<SomeClass>();

ref.lazySet(someClass);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think all you want is:

```
public class MyReference<T>{
    T reference;

    public void set(T ref){
      this.reference =ref;
    }
    public T get(){
      return this.reference;
    }

  }
```

You might consider adding delegating equals(), hashcode(), and toString().

Answer (score 0):

There is no synchronization cost to AtomicReference. From the description of the [java.util.concurrent.atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) package:

> A small toolkit of classes that support lock-free thread-safe programming on single variables.

**EDIT**
Based on your comments to your original post, it seems that you used the term "synchronization cost" in a non-standard way to mean thread-local cache flushing in general. On most architectures, reading a `volatile` is nearly as cheap as reading a non-volatile value. Any update to a shared variable is going to require cache flushing of at least that variable (unless you are going to abolish thread-local caches entirely). There isn't anything cheaper (performance-wise) than the classes in java.util.concurrent.atomic.

Comment: I think you missed the *"volatile"* used in *AtomicReference*.  *volatile* has a synchronization cost even though the keyword "synchronized" isn't used.  Which may be the source of your confusion.

Comment: There is a great difference semantically and in cost between volatile and synchronized.

Comment: @NoozNooz42 - `volatile` forces only the volatile variable to be updated in memory; with `synchronized`, all thread-local cached variables need to be updated. `volatile` tends to be _much_ less expensive than `synchronized`. See [this article by Brian Goetz](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/index.html) for details.

Comment: @Ted Hopp that is not entirely true.  All writes that occur before the write to a volatile field will become visible to any thread that subsequently reads that volatile field.  But you are correct a volatile write is ~1/3 less then a synchronized write.

Comment: @JohnVint - I'm curious--where did you get the statistic of ~1/3?

Answer (score 0):

all provided classes extending Reference has some special functionality attached, from atomic CaS to allowing the referenced object to be collected event thoguh a reference still exists to the object

you can create your own StringReference as [John Vint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8344618/731620) explained (or use a array with length==1) but there aren't that many uses for that though

Answer (score 0):

If your value is immutable, [java.util.Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) looks like a great option.