# Returning arrays to main method

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a question about returning an array from one method back to main. It is seriously starting to annoy me and I cannot wrap my brain around this. It seems as if even though I have changed the array in my method, when I go to display it in main it displays the old array. I'm trying to remove the duplicate numbers in my array and I know it works because I have stepped through it in the debugger yet after I return it and go back to main, it displays the whole array again! I know it must be something easy that I am missing here. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Here is my code...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numbers = new int[10];

    System.out.print("Enter 10 numbers: ");

    for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; ++x)
        numbers[x] = input.nextInt();

    eliminateDuplicates(numbers);

    for (int y = 0; y < numbers.length; ++y)
        System.out.print(numbers[y] + " ");
}


public static int[] eliminateDuplicates(int[] numbers) {
    int[] temp = new int[numbers.length];
    int size = 0;
    boolean found = false;

    for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; ++x) {

        for (int y = 0; y < temp.length && !found; ++y) {
            if (numbers[x] == temp[y])
                found = true;
        }
        if (!found) {
            temp[size] = numbers[x];
            size++;
        }
    found = false;
    }   

    int[] result = new int[size];
    for (int z = 0; z < result.length; ++z)
        result[z] = temp[z];

    return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this call:

```
 eliminateDuplicates(numbers);
```

You're ignoring the return value. Perhaps you wanted:

```
 numbers = eliminateDuplicates(numbers);
```

I sometimes wish that Java had a way of indicating that a method's return value shouldn't be ignored. It would save a lot of questions around `InputStream.read` as well...

Answer (score 3):

It should be: `numbers = eliminateDuplicates(numbers);`

You were essentially ignoring the returned result from the method.

Comment: Haha I knew it was something stupid. Thank you very much for the speedy answer... I feel quite dumb now. Self teaching is kind of rough sometimes

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
int[] result =eliminateDuplicates(numbers);
for (int y = 0; y < result.length; ++y)
    System.out.print(numbers[y] + " ");
```

Also, In your `eliminateDuplicates()` method, use `result` array directly by removing `temp` array. Or rename `temp` to `result` and return it. Following code is unnecessary :

```
int[] result = new int[size];
    for (int z = 0; z < result.length; ++z)
        result[z] = temp[z];
```

Comment: Yes but then wouldn't the size still be 10 and I would have 0's if there were numbers not included from the original array?

Answer (score 0):

In your main, try this:

```
numbers = eliminateDuplicates(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Method calling should be like this -

```
numbers = eliminateDuplicates(numbers);
```

You are not catching the result returning by eliminateDuplicates function.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, [parameters are passed by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068760/can-i-pass-parameters-by-reference-in-java), so you can't use `numbers` as an in/out parameter.

e.g. if you C# you could have done

```
 eliminateDuplicates(ref numbers);
```

But as others have pointed out, the most obvious issue is that you forgot to assign the result :)