# Write a method that takes a stack of integers as a parameter and that switches successive pairs of numbers starting at the bottom of the stack

Tags: java

If there are an odd number of values in the stack, the value at the top of the stack is not moved.

What's wrong..?

```
public static void switchPairs(Stack<Integer> st){
    Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    int size = st.size();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        
        int a = st.pop();
        int b = st.pop();
        q.add(a);
        q.add(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think is wrong? You are always operating with pairs, where should the last value go? This should give you exceptions because the stack is empty after a few iterations.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are several problems with your code:

1. You should go until size/2. You're pop-ing twice in each
   iteration. Then check if the length was odd and just add the last
   remaining element if so.
2. I think that your code only reverses your stack.

This is not tested but i think it should look something like this (also took the liberty to get rid of some useless variables - performance probably isnt an issue in this case).

Make your method return a stack and use it like this:

```
st = switchPairs(st);
```

And the method's body:

```
public Stack<Integer> switchPairs(Stack<Integer> st){
        Stack<Integer> q = new Stack<Integer>();   
        for(int i = 0; i < st.size()-1; i++){        
            q.push(st.elementAt(i+1));
            q.push(st.elementAt(i++)));
         }
         if(st.size()%2==1){
            q.push(st.pop());
         }
         return q;
}
```

To keep it void (usage taken from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1068786/869594))

```
AtomicReference<Stack<Integer>> ref = new AtomicReference<Stack<Integer>>(st);
switchPairs(ref);
st = ref.get();
```

And the method's body:

```
public void switchPairs(AtomicReference<Stack<Integer>> ref){
        Stack<Integer> q = new Stack<Integer>();   
        for(int i = 0; i < ref.get().size()-1; i++){        
            q.push(ref.get().elementAt(i+1));
            q.push(ref.get().elementAt(i++)));
         }
         if(ref.get().size()%2==1){
            q.push(ref.get().pop());
         }
         ref.set(q);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I tested it and it returns the first half of the original stack....?

Comment: I think it leaves it as a queue, i;m trying to change the original stack

Comment: I gave it another try. Sorry, I can't test java code. Tried the current implementation in C# and it works.

Comment: This works, but how would I write it as a void method?

Comment: Try making it void and instead of 'return q' try 'st = q'. I think Java only passes as value so this might work. I'm not sure though...

Comment: AtomicReference<Stack<Integer>> ref = new AtomicReference<Stack<Integer>>(st);
switchPairs(ref);
Change the method to get an AtomicReference<Stack<Integer>> parameter and get the object with the get() method on that reference. Right at the end do a 'parameter.set(q);

Comment: This is beyond what we've studied, i can't really understand or use it

Comment: I've updated the answer, maybe it makes it a bit more clear. You can also find the link that explains the AtomicReference<>. I'm afraid I can't help you with more than this.