# Why instance variable is null in below example

Tags: java

Can anyone please explain why instance variable 'root' is null?

```
public class Test{
    String root;

    public void assignRoot(){
        baseAssignment(root);
    }

    public void baseAssignment(String root){
        if(root == null){
            System.out.println("root:"+root);
            root = "assigned!";
            return;
        }

    }

    public String toString(){
        return root;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test t = new Test();
        t.assignRoot();
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
root:null
null
```

But i am expecting

```
root:null
assigned!
```

Comment: Try renaming the parameter name from root. Magically see it work ;)

Comment: I don't think this is a pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value problem. It is a problem of scope.

Comment: @cricket_007 The goal is not to just get things working but also to tech why something does or does not work.

Comment: @LutzHorn Fixing the scope problem is only one way to fix that problem, but it would result in ugly code. Understanding why OPs current approach doesn't work (and it is not because of scopes) is what is needed here.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to pass instance variables for method calls within the class:

```
public class Test{
    String root;

    public void assignRoot(){
        baseAssignment();
    }

    public void baseAssignment(){
        if(root == null){
            System.out.println("root:"+root);
            root = "assigned!";
            return;
        }

    }

    public String toString(){
        return root;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test t = new Test();
        t.assignRoot();
        System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ javac Test.java 
$ java Test
root:null
assigned!
```

or you can use `this.root="assigned!"` to refer the instance variable and not the local parameter.

Comment: Thanks for explanation!

Comment: @Pradeep welcome.. Kindly click on the tick mark on the left side of the answer and get the question solved :)

Answer (score 1):

You're just assigning a value to your local parameter `root` in your method, but not the class attribute `root`. Rename the parameter or use the `this`-keyword in front of it and it should work.
A good explanation, why it behaves like that, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1068786/2725299).

Comment: "global variable" doesn't belong in java world; I guess you mean class attribute?

Comment: @Preuk Yes, thanks. I'm really not the Java-guy, but I'm programming in C# and therefore I used this name. I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Because in `baseAssignment()` method you didn't initialize field `root`, you just change the local parameter `root`.

Instead of:

```
root = "assigned!";
```

you should write:

```
this.root = "assigned!";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(root == null){
        System.out.println("root:"+root);
        this.root = "assigned!";
```

You should use `this.root` as you only change the value of the String given as parameter named `root` too.

Answer (score 0):

That's my method parameters should always be  `final`. Making the parameter `root` `final` would cause a compile error on

```
root = "assigned!";
```

You must assign to `this.root`. Change your code to:

```
public void baseAssignment(final String root){
    if(root == null){
        System.out.println("root:"+root);
        this.root = "assigned!";
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Jack The question was closed as a duplicate more than an hour after I've posted my answer. Please don't try to be smart.

Comment: You haven't try to search that question before answering that question it's not a good practice first try to search related question if you don't find any than you have to give answer , by the way i am not smart like you.

Comment: @Jack I see. You are reading the "How to answer" manual, look up my answers, and point out any fault you find. Well, have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the one approach..

```
public void baseAssignment(String root){
    if(root == null){
        System.out.println("root:"+root);
      // root = "assigned!";
         this.root = "assigned!";
        return;
    }

}
```

or

```
public void baseAssignment(String root1){
    if(root1 == null){
        System.out.println("root:"+root);
        root = "assigned!";
        return;
    }

}
```

How it is explanation

```
Class MyClass{
String root="";
 public void baseAssignment(String root){
  root = "local variable"; // pointing to method local variable root 
  System.out.println("root:"+root);
  this.root = "class variable"; // pointing to class variable root 
  System.out.println("root:"+this.root);   
  }
 }
```

**Output of this:**

```
root:local variable
root:class variable
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why instead of just posting code so the author can learn.

Comment: when ever we are considering any variable with same name in this case root, inside method / block always all the operations performed on the local variable, to point the outer variable need to be explicitly mention with "this" as that'd be a class variable. please check the commented line on the 3rd block of my answer :)